# Postgres - Preferable to store byte array as BYTEA in Postgres or base64 encode the values and store them as TEXT

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm currently working to move some plaintext data in Postgres to an encrypted format.  I'm using Go and most cryptographic functions intake and output byte arrays. I also need to support key rotation and will generally by using the byte format to pack additional data at the front of values for metadata.

The columns are currently `TEXT` in Postgres 12.

Would there be any advantage to storing the output directly as `BYTEA` (in a new column) or would base64 encoding the values and storing them back into the same column provide better performance (faster reads/writes).

Both approaches would require an equal amount of refactoring to support other `SELECT` statements in the code.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but base64-encoding the bytes increases the required storage space by around 25%, and of course requires an encoding/decoding step in each direction. From those facts alone I would expect a `BYTEA` column to be more performant.

Comment: @larsks, 33%. 8 bits of output (one ASCII character) for every 6 bits of input (2**6 = 64).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely go with `bytea`. Converting to and from Base-64 is just an unnecessary waste of CPU time, and the result will waste storage space.